# iOS - JPSVolumeButtonHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c

I stumbled upon [this git repo](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler) in an SO post and was just giving it a trial run.  Basically, it's supposed to setup an observer for the volume button on your iphone.  I installed it with Cocoapods, and tried the example but wasn't able to detect volume up/down pushes.  Below is my code.  Does anyone have any experience working with this package?  is there something I'm missing?

I'm developing in XCode 7 and tested this on an iPhone 6.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JPSVolumeButtonHandler/JPSVolumeButtonHandler.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) JPSVolumeButtonHandler  *volumeHandler;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.outputLabel.text = @"";

    self.volumeHandler = [JPSVolumeButtonHandler volumeButtonHandlerWithUpBlock:^{
        self.outputLabel.text = @"  Up!  ";
    } downBlock:^{
        self.outputLabel.text = [self.outputLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"  Down!  "];
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `weak` reference to `JPSVolumeButtonHandler`. This means that this property will be released just after assigning to it (or to be more precise, at a point after exiting from `viewDidLoad`). Just change `weak` to `strong` and everything will be working just fine.